# Как посмотреть какие команды выполняет mingw?

Tags: c++, c, mingw

Насколько я понял, когда я набираю `gcc`, запускается драйвер, вызывающий другие программы (препроцессор, компилятор, линковщик). Как посмотреть с какими ключами он их вызывает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как посмотреть с какими ключами он их вызывает?

Просто добавь `-v` (`--verbose`) в аргументы, в числе прочего gcc выдаст команды запуска транслятора, ассемблера и при необходимости линкера. Препроцессор AFAIK сегодня совмещён с транслятором и как отдельная сущность (процесс) не запускается.

**hw.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**gcc -v ./hw.c -o hw**

```
Используются внутренние спецификации.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper
Целевая архитектура: x86_64-linux-gnu
Параметры конфигурации: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Модель многопоточности: posix
gcc версия 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'hw' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu ./hw.c -quiet -dumpbase hw.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase hw -version -o /tmp/cc7mGbkD.s
GNU C11 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) версия 6.3.0 20170516 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        скомпилировано GNU C версия 6.3.0 20170516, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version 0.15
эвристики GGC: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
несуществующий каталог "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu" проигнорирован
несуществующий каталог "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include" проигнорирован
порядок поиска для #include "...":
порядок поиска для #include <...>:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
Конец списка поиска.
GNU C11 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) версия 6.3.0 20170516 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        скомпилировано GNU C версия 6.3.0 20170516, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version 0b8e5d7f3c4236757ee0871869b8330f3
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'hw' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccUiw1bw.o /tmp/cc7mGbkD.s
GNU ассемблер, версия 2.28 (x86_64-linux-gnu); используется BFD версии (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.28
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'hw' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccnJVd5o.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -o hw /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../.. /tmp/ccUiw1bw.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'hw' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
.15
эвристики GGC: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: b8e5d7f3c4236757ee0871869b8330f3
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'hw' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccUiw1bw.o /tmp/cc7mGbkD.s
GNU ассемблер, версия 2.28 (x86_64-linux-gnu); используется BFD версии (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.28
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'hw' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccnJVd5o.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -o hw /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../.. /tmp/ccUiw1bw.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'hw' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Здесь:
 `cc1` — транслятор
 `as` — ассемблер
 `collect2` — линкер

**Update**

По факту [`collect2`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html#Collect2) — это не сам линкер, а обёртка над ним от gcc, которая используется для реализации функций начальной инициализации (конструкторов глобальных объектов) при запуске программы (читай — внутренней магии). Вызов непосредственно внутреннего линкера можно увидеть, например передав `collect2` всё тот же аргумент `-v`, например через gcc: `-Wl,-v`. Аргументы `ld` не должны отличаться от `collect2`.

Comment: А ld что такое если collect2 это линкер? Тоже драйвер?

Comment: @Andru, добавил в ответ...

Comment: А -Wl что делает?

Comment: @Andru, [`-Wl,<option>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-Wl) передают <option> линкеру.